# Why am I getting TypeError: ENS is not a constructor when using ensjs library?

Tags: web3js, javascript, ethereumjs, ens

I am trying to get address using ens domain but when I use the below code snippet it gives me `TypeError: ENS is not a constructor`, have I written it in the right way?

```
import ENS, { getEnsAddress } from '@ensdomains/ensjs';
const provider = "https://ropsten.infura.io/v3/project_id";
const ens = new ENS({ provider, ensAddress: getEnsAddress('1') });
const name = ens.name('abcd.eth').getAddress();
name.then((str) => {
  console.log(str);
});
```